# How to customize a Graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need help to customize a graph using Matplotlib.
I want to draw a graph like this.
[image]

My python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.loadtxt('input.txt', delimiter = ',')

x = np.arange(0,64)
y = np.arange(0,64)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)

#customize colorbar
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['royalblue','blue','red'])    

im = ax.contourf(y,x,data,cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

and my output is:

[image]

So what should i do ?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @DizietAsahi x and y axis (i need 0,16,32,64) and the shades of color